# import in another file

Tags: python, class, module

I am writing a program using pygame in python. I'd like to put the class definition in another .py file, and import it. My directory structure looks like this:

```
main.py
game.py
__init__.py
```

`__init__.py` is currently empty.

main.py is the main program which imports the class definitions from game.py and uses it. There are some other imports and global variables which both game.py and main.py use, like this:

```
import sys
import pygame
import time
import itertools
import os


red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
darkBlue = (0,0,128)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
pink = (255,200,200)
yellow = (240, 240,20)
dark_yellow = (240, 240,200)
```

I was able to get the code work by placing the above header in both files. However this seems wasteful/redundant/horrible. Can it be placed in `__init__.py` (didn't work) or some other common place?

Comment: Put the global variables into one module—whether `game.py` or otherwise—and have all the other modules use them via import—e.g., `game.red` instead of `red`. As for the imports, you almost certainly don't need them all in every module; only put them in the modules that use them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about global variables. That works.
Regarding importing modules, you seem to say that there is no other way but repetition, and better isolation of functionality is key.

Comment: Basically, yeah. But I doubt your current code is actually using all of those imports in both modules. If you’re not using itertools anywhere in main, just don’t import it there. And so on.

Comment: Yes, I was able to remove most of it except pygame. pygame is being used in both places, and I am not too happy importing it twice - it feels wrong/clunky.

Comment: If you're using a module in two different places, there's nothing wrong with importing it in both places. It's better for each module to be as self-contained as possible, with a clear "interface" (what it imports, and what it exports); the fact that there will often be a tiny bit of overlap between two modules is not a problem. If there's a whole lot of overlap, that usually means there's something you need to refactor into another module entirely, with a much narrower interface, so the other modules only need to use that module.

Comment: importing modules twice isn't clunky because it's never actually run twice, once it is imported it will be reused in the same process, you can see that by checking the `id()` of a module whnever you import it, basically it means that after the initial import every subsequent import behaves more like an `#include` from c/c++ it just means you can access that code